# Pattern match on HXT does not work as expected

Tags: haskell, hxt

For example, I have a `div` containing a few `p`s and others, and I want to map the `p`s with show.

```
defShow :: NTree XNode -> String
defShow (NTree (XTag div' _) contents)
  | show div' == "div" = intercalate "\n" $ map defShow contents
defShow p@(NTree (XTag p' []) _)
  | show p' == "p" = show p
defShow x = error $ show x
```

But with testing data as following, this does not work. I mean the whole node, not just the `p` node.

```
NTree (XTag "div" [NTree (XAttr "class") [NTree (XText "refsect2") []]])
      [ NTree (XText "\n") []
      , NTree (XTag "p" []) [SOME_TEXT_NODE] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `show` in the logic of your program. You can use `mkName` to convert a `String` to a `QName`.

```
defShow :: NTree XNode -> String
defShow (NTree (XTag div' _) contents)
  | div' == mkName "div" = intercalate "\n" $ map defShow contents
defShow p@(NTree (XTag p' []) _)
  | p' == mkName "p" = show p
defShow x = ""
```